# What lookouts or peaks in Charlevoix can I access by rental car?

Tags: quebec

My grandparents  (of age 79 and 77)  from Toronto

1. are contemplating travelling to [Charlevoix](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.6324925,-71.36139,7.25z) (see the red polygon below) for leaf-peeping.
2. will rent a sedan, but please edify us if they need a SUV.
3. can e-bike or walk, but not manually pedal a bicycle for too long or hike.
4. will lodge at  Hôtel Le Germain Québec (in Québec City), Hôtel & Spa Le Germain Charlevoix, and  OTL Gouverneur Saguenay.

Are there higher elevations or apices, accessible by rental car, to sightsee the fall foliage?

[image]

Comment: @gerrit Post this as an answer, not a comment. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't live anywhere close and have never even been there, but I created an
[overpass turbo map](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/KEi) for you. This map displays every spot that is tagged as `tourism=viewpoint` in [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/). You still have to manually check the spots for eligibility and reachability, for example using the [`terrain` feature of Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/36eJBm67MW7NQGUX9) (I have no idea how to do this in overpass), but at least you get a starting point without knowing the area.

[image: overpass turbo map]

As shown in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/249597/130798), it would be theoretically possible to further filter for elevation, amongst other things, but I'm not good enough at the system to do this. To create the map above, I just followed the instructions from [this article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_by_tag) using the tag `tourism=viewpoint`.